# New 1hp pool pump trips breaker or starts to smell after start up

Tags: electrical

I installed new 1 hp inground pool pump. Trips the breaker or starts to smell like burning electrical 30 secs after running. Meter says pump is pulling 25 amps when suppose to pull 11..

Comment: Check or have the pump inspected.  What you are experiencing seems about right for something pulling more than twice the amps expected.

Comment: is it 120 or 240 ? Disconnect the ground and try again, without touching the pump

Comment: Is the pump actually turning?  Is flow actually happening?  A motor that is stalled or turning slowly against very high load will draw much higher current. It should trip the breaker. That's what breakers are for, that's why Code says install the smallest breaker that does not nuisance-trip.

Comment: Did you open all the valves after replacing the pump?

Comment: Recheck your wiring and use the diagram on the new pump, not the old one.

Comment: had a electrician check the wiring and test it..all was good. I have 122 volts to my outlet..which is good.pt Had good suction.pump was pulling water no problem.started smelling something shut it off.Brand new pump.have been told by someone that if my wiring to my outlet is not thick enough that could effect the amps..but electrician has said that is not true.thank you for your response..

Comment: Was the old pump 120v? and is the new one 120v or 240v?  If a 240v motor is supplied with only 120v it will draw a LOT OF POWER.  From what you said, your new pump is probably already toast or close to it.

Comment: The breaker has tripped a few times within 30 seconds of it being on..sometimes not but the smell of burning electrical tells me to shit it down